# volatile unsigned int * const

Tags: c

In the following line of code, what is the purpose of the `const` keywords?

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR = (unsigned int *)0x10009000;
```

I understand the `volatile unsigned int *` bit, but why is `const` there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`const` and `volatile` are called "type qualifiers". Their syntax is one of the most confusing things in C.

First of all we have the case with an ordinary variable. You usually write the type qualifier before the variable name: `const int x;`, but is also fine to write it after the variable name: `int const x;`. The meaning is the same, the latter syntax is just there to confuse.

When declaring a pointer, you are concerned with two types: the type of the pointer itself, and the type pointed at. With ordinary pointers, this is trivial: `int* x` means that the pointer type is pointer-to-int, and the pointed-to-type is int.

If the pointed-to-type is const int, the pointer is declared as `const int* x`. The pointer is of type pointer-to-const-int, and the pointed-to type is const int. If you want to confuse everyone, you can also write `int const* x`, it is equivalent.

Let us say that we want the pointer itself to be constant as well. For some reason we want to block the programmer from changing the address pointed at. For example, perhaps the pointer is to be stored in read-only memory of an embedded system. A constant pointer to data, is declared as `int*const x;` with the const keyword after the *. The pointed-to-type in this case is `int`, and *not* `const int`. (I try to write the const together with the *, with no space in between, to give emphasis that the *pointer* is constant)

If we want the pointed-to-type to be constant as well, we would have to combine the two above declarations: `const int*const x;` means a constant pointer pointing at a constant int.

```
const int x;          // x is a constant data variable
int const x;          // x is a constant data variable

const int* x;         // x is a non-constant pointer to constant data
int const* x;         // x is a non-constant pointer to constant data 

int*const x;          // x is a constant pointer to non-constant data

const int*const x;    // x is a constant pointer to constant data
```

In the above examples I have used the type qualifier `const`. But `volatile` is also a type qualifier, and it behaves in exactly the same manner! It is possible to declare non-volatile pointers to volatile data etc.

And finally, it is possible to combine different type qualifiers. For example a `volatile const int*` is a non-constant, non-volatile pointer to volatile const data. Once again we have the wonderful option to mix the order of these to confuse, so we can also write `volatile int const *` or `int volatile const *` etc and it all means the same.

Comment: +1, good explanation of type qualifiers, but the OP ask why it's used in his code

Comment: Thanks. One quick question. Is `int* x` equivalent to `int* int x`?

Comment: `volatile const int *ptr*` -> pointer to a data that has been given only Read permission by the code, but can be modified by external events(interrupts etc)

Comment: I would argue that *"the latter syntax is just there to confuse"* is wrong, as the latter syntax is actually the standard. `const` applies to the type directly to the left of it, but as an exception, `const` can also be put at the far left end, and then it applies to the first type. This makes sense when you look at const pointers.

Comment: @AndersTornblad No, you are wrong. C11 6.7.2, "...the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers." Together with 6.7.3/5, this allows complete nonsense like `const const int const long const unsigned const auto const long x;`, which is 100% equivalent to `const unsigned long long x;`. (And yes you don't have to initialize a const in C...) This is one of the more brain-damaged parts of the C standard. ->

Comment: What we should use as guidance is the future language directions 6.11.5 which dictates that the storage-class specifier should only be placed at the beginning. Good practice and industry de-facto standard is: storage-class specified, type-qualifier, type-specifier. Anything else is gibberish and possibly obsolete C.

Comment: Ah, you are completely right. I was far inside my C++ bubble. :)

Answer (score 6):

**I understand the `volatile unsigned int *` bit, but why is `const` there?**

It means that the pointer is constant, which means that the pointer cannot(rather should not) point to any other address.

Note the following, constructs:

```
volatile unsigned int * const UART0DR =
```

Pointer is constant here.

---

```
volatile unsigned int const * UART0DR =
```

The pointed address is constant here.

---

```
volatile unsigned int const * const UART0DR =
```

The pointed address as well as the pointer is constant in this case.

Comment: Thanks. So is the `const` for some sort of compiler optimisation?

Comment: @Randomblue: It is a qualifier which tells the compiler that this particular entity is constant and will not change.This helps the compiler to point out errors in same cases while also *may* allow the compiler to apply optimizations.Most ipmortantly it tells the users of your source code a vital information about the particular variable just by reading its declaration.

Comment: "The pointed address is constant here."  Rather, _the contents_ of the pointed-to address.

Answer (score 2):

From http://cdecl.org

```
volatile unsigned int *const a
=>
declare a as const pointer to volatile unsigned int
```