# Declaring Pointer Error Message: "expected an identifier"

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, embedded, msp432

I am trying to define some pointers to the port registers on my board MSP432, however, in the following code when I attempt to declare my pointers, I keep receiving the following error:

> ```
> "../main.c", line 11: error #41: expected an identifier
> "../main.c", line 11: error #80: expected a type specifier
> ```

I have tried several different alternations, but keep receiving the same error and am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "msp.h"
#include <stdint.h>

void main()
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;

    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_HOLD;

    uint8_t * P1IN = (uint8_t *)0x40004C00;
    uint8_t * P1SEL0 = (uint8_t *)0x40004C0A;
    uint8_t * P1SEL1 = (uint8_t *)0x40004C0C;
    uint8_t * P1OUT = (uint8_t *)0x40004C02;
    uint8_t * PDIR = (uint8_t *)0x40004C04;

.....
```

Comment: It's very likely that your compiler isn't up-to-date to the C99 standard, which added features like being able to declare variables anywhere. Put all variable declarations at the top of the functions, before any other statements (like e.g. your assignment to `WDT_A->CTL`).

Comment: Where is the declaration/definition for `WDT_A`? I don't see it anywhere. Do you expect it to be in `msp.h`? Is it really there?

Comment: Thanks for the help! However I tried declaring my variable at the beginning, at still received the same error.

Comment: The WDT_A line in included in the msp.h, and it just turns the watchdog timer off on my board.

Comment: I figured it out, for some reason my variable names weren't working, and when I changed the variable names it compiled!

Comment: So likely there were already defined by the compiler in some register map header. Btw, those pointers must be `volatile` qualified or the code might decide to bug out.

Comment: You should definitely add the `volatile` keyword and `const` may be helpful too as the address of the register doesn't change (see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734326/volatile-unsigned-int-const)